# Loadbalancing simple MVC3 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, load-balancing

I have a simple MVC3 app in .NET 4.0 framework which does not use sessions. It uses windows integration (AD groups) for authentication. It is deployed on 2 servers (both Windows 2003 and IIS 6). To get MVC3 to work under IIS 6 I have a workaround wherein I added a wildcard map. The app works fine on both the machines when I access them directly.

I would like to use a HW load balancer so that I can rotate between both the servers seamlessly. And since my app does not have any sessions this should be fairly easy (I hope). What I would like to do is make sure the app is running on the server before LB sends the request to that app. It could be as simple as checking if keepalive.htm file exists in that app. Since the number of users for this particular app is very low I do not want to device a very complicated solution. I tried implementing the keepalive solution but I keep getting 401 error. Even after I made the file readable by everyone and gave it anonymous access (so no authentication required) it still gives me the same error. I have a feeling that my workaround to get MVC3 to work for IIS 6 is getting in the way.

Any ideas on how to load balance a simple MVC3 app so that Loadbalancer can check if the app is up before forwarding the request?

Thanks for the help.